# Ceiling Light Installation: Junction Box or SLIM Led Driver Differences

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, junction-box

What are the advantages/disadvantages between using a Junction Box Ceiling Light Installation or a Slim LED Driver box installation?

My ceiling has space to incorporate either option.

I am wondering what the best option is, is the industry going towards more LED Driver box ?

The Slim LEDs come with their own junction box.

**Examples:**

[LED Round Color Select-able Flat Panel Recessed Trim](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Feit-Electric-5-or-6-in-J-Box-12-Watt-Dim-90-CRI-White-Integrated-LED-Round-Color-Selectable-Flat-Panel-Recessed-Trim-74206-CA/306897868?NCNI-5)

[Ultra Slim 6 in. Canless Color Selectable CCT Integrated LED Recessed Light Trim Downlight 900 Lumens Dimmable](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Ultra-Slim-6-in-Canless-Selectable-CCT-Integrated-LED-Recessed-Light-Trim-All-in-One-Downlight-900-Lumens-Dimmable-53807101/306179204?MERCH=REC-)

**Slim LED with Driver Box:**

Installation Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4fHshRd3g0

[image]

**Junction box Install**

[image]

searching to understand comparison, vs. for new house

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases a box is required. The advantage today is the slim may be cheaper, but in the future you may be tied to a slim box.  This could become a problem when all the mfg’s are only making replacement modules for full sized boxes because of the millions or hundred of millions of full sized boxes currently in use. How many slim boxes were ever installed?

The other consideration is that if other wires are in the box to connect to other lights, there is a minimum number of cubic inches required to accommodate those wires, so in this case, a larger size may be required today and provides more options when this light fails (LED’s rarely fail but the electronics driving them sure do).

Comment: thanks, so which one should I get? regular junction box, no slim led driver? money isn't really a factor for me

Comment: btw, my slim LEDs I bought come with their own junction box I believe

Comment: @earlwaltonluv3462 if money's no object today or in the future, use whichever one you want. If you want to be prepared for the future, put in a large junction box & install the slim box inside it. That gives you the most options for the future.

Comment: I agree with freeman that’s what I was trying to point out saving a small amount today may put you in a bind later. if you go with the slimline today and when it fails in the future cost may still not be an issue the inconvenience of a different style and possibility of having to add boxes could be a headache eliminated by installing boxes today. +